# Updating SUM when cell value change in DataTable

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having some problem with my c# code.
What I'm trying to do is to add new row to my dataTable and then calculate some things and insert into specific cells.

Here is what I'v got :

```
    object sumAmount;

    object sumDest;

    object sumWhole;

    DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
    row["number"] = "1";
    dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

    sumAmount  = dataTable.Compute("Sum(amount)", "");

    dataTable.Rows[dataTable.Rows.Count - 1][all] = Int32.Parse(sumAmount.ToString());

    sumDest = dataTable.Compute("Sum(dest)", "");

    dataTable.Rows[dataTable.Rows.Count - 1][columnNumber] = Int32.Parse(sumDest.ToString());

    sumWhole = dataTable.Compute("Sum(wholeAmount)", "");

    dataTable.Rows[dataTable.Rows.Count - 1][allTogether] = Int32.Parse(sumWhole.ToString());
```

It works correctly for the first time.
But when i change some cell value then I'm recalculating this with this same code (part with dataTable =) and when I'm doing it the cell value isnt replaced, this added.

Example:

When I had this :

```
 10    3    13
  6    1     7
  2    0     2
 18    4    22  << This is SUM
```

And I insert 1 in some cell in 2nd column im expecting this :

```
 10    3    13
  6    1     7
  2    1     3
 18    5    23
```

But what im getting is :

```
 10    3    13
  6    1     7
  2    1     3
 38    9    45
```

As you can see these values just being added, but I don't get it why?
Can someone help me finding bug in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a spreadsheet, so it doesnt know to exclude the last row from the formula.  It looks like the 3rd column is also a Total?  If so, *that* can be an expression which the `DataTable` maintains:

```
dtXYZ = new DataTable();
dtXYZ.Columns.Add("X", typeof(Int32));
dtXYZ.Columns.Add("Y", typeof(Int32));
dtXYZ.Columns.Add("Z", typeof(Int32));
dtXYZ.Columns["Z"].Expression="X+Y";
```

The columns are typed so that `X+Y` adds.  Add some data probably like you already are:

```
dtXYZ.Rows.Add(new object[]{10, 3});
dtXYZ.Rows.Add(new object[]{6, 1});
dtXYZ.Rows.Add(new object[]{2, 0});

dtXYZ.Rows.Add(dtXYZ.Compute("sum(X)", ""),
            dtXYZ.Compute("sum(Y)", ""));
```

The last column does need to be computed, the `Expression` will take care of that. One way to use `Compute` and not include the grand total row, would be to remove and readd it each time:

```
int nRows = dtXYZ.Rows.Count - 1;
dtXYZ.Rows.RemoveAt(nRows);
dtXYZ.Rows.Add( dtXYZ.Compute("sum(X)", ""),
               dtXYZ.Compute("sum(Y)", ""));
```

But rather than doing that just to be able to use `Compute`, you can do the summing yourself with some extension methods and post the new value:

```
int nRows = dtXYZ.Rows.Count - 1;
dtXYZ.Rows[nRows ]["X"] = dtXYZ.AsEnumerable()
               .Take(nRows)
               .Sum(x => x.Field<int>("X"));

dtXYZ.Rows[nRows ]["Y"] = dtXYZ.AsEnumerable()
               .Take(nRows)
               .Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Y"));
```

[image]

Or even a loop would work.  Either way, remember you dont have to fiddle with the last column if it is based on an `Expression` - in fact you cant.