# Apply Formula Cell to a DataGridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, formula

I want to add formula cell in a `DataGridView`. Is there any custom `DataGridView` to do this?

Example:

```
grid[4, column].Text = string.Format("=MAX({0}6:{0}{1})", columnAsString, grid.RowCount);
```

Comment: If you are looking for a custom control, take a look at [Free .NET Spreadsheet Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691749/Free-NET-Spreadsheet-Control). It supports [formula](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691749/Free-NET-Spreadsheet-Control#Formula)

Comment: You can use `DataTable` that supports [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) and bind it to `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is there any custom DataGridView to do this?**

Off-topic, but if you are looking for a custom control, take a look at [Free .NET Spreadsheet Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691749/Free-NET-Spreadsheet-Control). Also it supports [formula](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691749/Free-NET-Spreadsheet-Control#Formula).

**If writing code for calculation is an option for you**

If writing code for calculation is an option for you, to calculate value of a cell based on values of some other cells you can use `CellFormatting` event of `DataGridView` and put calculation logic there. Also handle `CellEndEdit` and call `InvalidateCell` or `Invalidate` to force update value of cell after each in reference cells.

Here is an example:

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("B", typeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        dt.Rows.Add(r.Next(100));
    grid.DataSource = dt;
    grid.CellFormatting += grid_CellFormatting;
    grid.CellEndEdit += grid_CellEndEdit;
}
void grid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    grid.Invalidate();
}
void grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as DataGridView;
    var parameterColumnName = "A";       //Parameter column name
    var start = 0;                       //Start row index for formula
    var end = grid.RowCount - 1;         //End row index for formula
    var resultRowIndex = 0;              //Result row index
    var resultColumnName = "B";          //Result column name
    if (e.RowIndex == resultRowIndex &&
        grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == resultColumnName)
    {
        var list = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1)
              .Select(i => grid.Rows[i].Cells[parameterColumnName].Value)
              .Where(x => x != null && x != DBNull.Value)
              .Cast<int>();
        if (list.Any())
            e.Value = list.Max();
    }
}
```

**Note**

The solution is not limited to `DataTable`, it will work regardless of the `DataSource` which you use for `DataGridView` and you can use any kind of data source in this solution.

Comment: Which method is faster? Using the specific control or the last one with the events?

Comment: The event approach is fast enough. I didn't try the linked control, but it seems it has lot's of functionalities.

Comment: By the way, you can only choose one answer as accepted. But you can vote as many answers as you find useful, including the accepted one. Currently you made this post unaccepted after you had accepted it :)

Comment: Also the solution is not limited to `DataTable`, it will work regardless of the `DataSource` which you use for `DataGridView`.

Comment: I checked `DataGridView` in these states: Bound to a `List<T>`, to a `DataTable`, without `DataSource` and created columns and rows using `RowCount` and `ColumnCount`, without `DataSource` and creating columns and rows using `Columns.Add` and `Rows.Add` and in all cases it worked properly. I suspect you put `grid.CellFormatting += grid_CellFormatting;` in a place which doesn't run. For example you may forgot to assign `Form1_Load` to `Load` event of `Form`.

Comment: Also about `CellEndEdit`, it's just for grids which are editable and if your grid is read-only, you don't need it.

Comment: You can use `PropertyGrid` at design mode and assign event handlers to controls. Also you can do it in code. But don't use both code and design mode, because events will be attached twice.

Answer (score 8):

In many, many cases the data is not actually in the `DataGridView`, but elsewhere like a `DataTable` or a collection of some sort (like `List<T>`).  The control simply presents a view of the data to the user.

There are several ways to do something along the lines of what you want.  For both of these, the data actually resides in a `DataTable`.

#### Expressions

A `DataColumn` can be assigned an [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).  Consult the link for the types of Expression, keywords, operators and functions supported.  The following will create an expression based columns to multiple `Quantity * Price` for some rows:

```
dtSample = new DataTable();
dtSample.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item", typeof(string)));
dtSample.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(int)));
dtSample.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Price", typeof(decimal)));
dtSample.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Sale", typeof(decimal)));

// assign expression using the col names
dtSample.Columns[3].Expression = "(Quantity * Price)";
```

After some random data is added, as well as an empty row, the `DataTable` will maintain those columns for you.  This works like you probably want it to: if the user (or code) changes the value of a `Quantity` or `Price` cell, the `Sale` column contents is automatically updated.  (an image is later after the second method).

`Expressions` work at the row level.  There is not an all-rows/table-wise counter part for something like a TOTALS row - this is because the data would often come from a `DataSource`.  Adding calculated rows could accidentally add new data to that source (like a DB). But it is not hard to do in code:

#### Event Driven Calculations

Similar to the DGV `CellFormatting` answer given, you can respond to events from the `DataTable` such as `RowChanged`.  There you can perform whatever operations and update the table.

```
...create table and columns
...populate table
// hook up event
dtSample.RowChanged += RowChanged;
```

Then in the event, the code calculates an over all per unit average to display in the last row.  In some cases, you may be able to use the `Compute()` method of the `DataTable`.  Unlike an `Expression`, it isnt updated automatically and  [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38818990/1070452) it can be clumsy to update.

With typed data in a DataTable, it is fairly easy to perform calculations in response to events:

```
private void RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    // number of rows used 
    int Rows = dtSample.Rows.Count-1;
    if (e.Row == dtSample.Rows[Rows]) return;

    // display TotalSales / TotalUnits
    // get the units
    int TotUnits = dtSample
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => !r.IsNull("Quantity"))
        .Take(Rows)
        .Sum(n => n.Field<int>("Quantity"));
    
    // sum Sales, divide and display in DGV
    dtSample.Rows[Rows]["Price"] = dtSample
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => !r.IsNull("Sale"))
        .Take(Rows)
        .Sum(n => n.Field<decimal>("Sale")) / TotUnits;
}
```

[image]

The "Sales" column is automatically maintained via an `Expression` which means you cannot manually do anything to that column.

The overall average price at the bottom is also "automatically" updated, the difference is that we had to write a smattering of code to do so.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are dealing with pure data strings, you need to have a thread running in the background to do the calculations and update the UI accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could try:

Handle the cell value changed event to detect when one of the cells used in the calculation changes and calculate the appropriate value.  Something like this (try it in a new project)

```
Public Class Form1
  Private WithEvents DGV As New DataGridView
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DGV.SetBounds(20, 50, 400, 200)
    Controls.Add(DGV)
    DGV.Columns.Add("Qty", "Qty")
    DGV.Columns.Add("Price", "Price")
    DGV.Columns.Add("Total", "Total")
    DGV.Columns("Total").ReadOnly = True
    DGV.RowCount = 5
  End Sub

  Private Sub DGV_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV.CellValueChanged
    If e.ColumnIndex = DGV.Columns("Qty").Index Or e.ColumnIndex = DGV.Columns("Price").Index Then
      DGV("Total", e.RowIndex).Value = CInt(DGV("Qty", e.RowIndex).Value) * CDbl(DGV("Price", e.RowIndex).Value)
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Or rather than reading your file direct to the datagridview read it into a datatable and bind the grid to the datatable.  You can then add an expression column in the datatable to do the calculation.  Something like this:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private WithEvents DGV As New DataGridView
  Private DT As New DataTable
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DGV.SetBounds(20, 50, 400, 200)
    Controls.Add(DGV)
    DT.Columns.Add("Qty", GetType(Int32))
    DT.Columns.Add("Price", GetType(Double))
    DT.Columns.Add("Total", GetType(Double))
    DT.Columns("Total").Expression = "Qty * Price"
    DGV.DataSource = DT
  End Sub
End Class
```