# Arithmetic operations in a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView, where, in Column 5, I have a value from the database; in Column 8 an user will enter a value, then I need

```
[Column 8] - [Column 5] = [Column 9]
```

I tried this:

```
Private Sub DgvAllocation_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DgvAllocation.CellEndEdit
    Dim DocNo As String

    If e.ColumnIndex = 8 Then
        DocNo = DgvAllocation.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(8).Value - DgvAllocation.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Value
        DocNo = DgvAllocation.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(9).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

but its not working

Comment: Maybe you want `[Column 9] = [Column 8] - [Column 5]`? What's the content of these Columns? What data type? Try setting `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict On`, so you are *forced* to work with the actual data types you have there.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? `but its not working` is extremelly unclear, please add more details.

Comment: [Column 5] have Number data type in oracle 11g .....  [Column 8] is non database  user input column .... [Column 9] is calculated column

Comment: Did you mean `DgvAllocation.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(9).Value = DocNo` ?

Comment: If your data source is a data table, you can easily add a new column having an expression, then you don't need to do the calculation yourself and the column will do it automatically. For complicated calculation, you can rely on end edit event. Take a look at the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38852389/3110834).

Comment: Also, '*but its not working*' is not a good problem description. It doesn't tell us anything. It's not clear if it's throwing an exception or just does nothing or showing the wrong result or ....

Comment: Dear Reza , i want [Column 9] = [Column 8] - [Column 5] ...[Column 5] have Number data type in oracle 11g ..... [Column 8] is user input column  (non database) .... [Column 9] is calculated column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't assigned a new value to the cell in column 9.  You want to do something like this:

```
    DocNo = DgvAllocation.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(8).Value - DgvAllocation.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Value
    DgvAllocation.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(9).Value = DocNo
```