# Display Image in datagridview cell that have text type

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I have an `Image` column with `varchar(max)` data type in a SQL Server table.

I can't hold the Image in specific cell but if I work with columns everything works correctly

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bunifuCustomDataGrid1.RowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < bunifuCustomDataGrid1.ColumnCount; j++)
    {
        if (bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != DBNull.Value)
        {
            DataGridViewImageColumn ci = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Columns.RemoveAt(j);
            ci.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ok_24px;
            bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Columns.Insert(j, ci);
        }
    }
}

bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Update();
```

So what should I do to work with `DataGridViewImageCell` not with `DataGridViewImageColumn` ?

Comment: **WHY** are you storing a (binary) image in a **string**-based column? That doesn't make any sense at all - that column should be of type `varbinary(max)` - not `varchar`

Comment: @marc_s Thank you I don't Know what to told you I didn't never check this !!!

Comment: Do you store the file path or the image binary data th ine varchar cell? If it's a file path you need to load it, otherwise you need to convert it to a Image. In all cases, you should hide the it in the grid and use it to create [calculated column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/unbound-column-to-a-data-bound-datagridview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097370/calculation-in-datagridview-column • https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852389/apply-formula-cell-to-a-datagridview

Comment: You can replace any cell individually by any other cell with any cell type, if that is what you really want..